# How to resolve not allowed to bind service intent?

Tags: android

I am running`my email`application this is same as system application `email` android 4.0.Gives an error when running application.

```
Caused by:java.lang.SecurityException:Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=com.android.email.EXCHANGE_INTENT }
```

Comment: how can one help you if you do not provide enough information? paste some code... tell exactly when this happens..

Comment: Please check permission for security exception

Comment: <manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.email1"
    android:versionCode="401000"
    android:versionName="4.0.1"
    >

    <original-package
        android:name="com.android.email" /><!-- Grant permission to system apps to access provider 
    <permission
        android:name="com.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER"
        
        android:label="@string/permission_access_provider_label"
        <uses-permission
       android:name="com.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER"/>

Comment: Actulally I have taken android source code email app 4.0.I want to edit that default app of android.but when i run that application that time it give such type of exception.not getting why this happening.I ahve change my package name also.

Comment: which particular permission i have to check

Comment: have you added the Read.Contact permission in menifest.xml.Can you put menifest file permission here????So i can tell you which you didnt added.

Comment: <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>

Comment: <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>

Comment: <permission
        android:name="com.android.email.permission.READ_ATTACHMENT"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.MESSAGES"

        android:label="@string/permission_read_attachment_label"
        android:description="@string/permission_read_attachment_desc"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.email.permission.READ_ATTACHMENT"/>

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>

Comment: @NiteshKhosla I have added all permission but exception is not resolved java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=com.android.email.EXCHANGE_INTENT }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application certificates allows the system to grant or deny applications access to [signature-level permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel)

This email application from the android source code is using android:protection level for that.First delete the system app and you can install your application.

Comment: How to delete app from emulator

Comment: Just follow the instruction as mentioned [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/10004/accessing-android-market-from-android-sdk/)

this make your system/app folder in write mode from where you can add delete any app as per your requirement

Cheers :)

Comment: You are facing problem due to same permission name. Kindly make sure that the permission name in android manifest must be package_name.your_string. And also just make sure that the name of permission in the manifest should same as in java files